# The Command to start Coldfusion server exits with errors in Command Box

Tags: coldfusion, commandbox

I have been all over trying to figure out what this error means. The project has been just given to me and I have never done anything with cold fusion.

Any help would be appreciated.

What happens is when I try and start the command box I get this error and the server stops.

The command I run to start this server is

```
server start cfengine=adobe@11 console=true
```

```
[INFO ] Runwar: ******************************************************************************
[INFO ] Runwar: Starting RunWAR 4.8.5
[INFO ] Runwar: Binding HTTP on localhost:8282
[INFO ] Runwar: Enabling HTTP/2
[INFO ] Runwar: Servlet Context: /
[INFO ] Runwar: Log Directory: C:\Users\Aaron\.CommandBox\server\DE7764989AC6E02101EEFD566DEBC404-cherokee-leaseapps\adobe-11.0.19.314546\logs
[INFO ] Runwar: ******************************************************************************
[INFO ] Runwar: Parsing 'C:\Users\Aaron\.CommandBox\server\DE7764989AC6E02101EEFD566DEBC404-cherokee-leaseapps\adobe-11.0.19.314546\WEB-INF\web.xml'
[INFO ] Runwar: Creating deployment [default] in C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\dev\cherokee-leaseapps
[INFO ] 05/31 16:08:18 INFO License Service: Flex 1.5 CF Edition enabled
[INFO ] 05/31 16:08:18 INFO Starting Flex 1.5 CF Edition
[INFO ] 05/31 16:08:18 INFO Macromedia Flex Build: 87315.134646
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.CfmServlet.init(CfmServlet.java:97)
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:121)
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
[ERROR]         at runwar.Server.createServletDeployment(Server.java:1360)
[ERROR]         at runwar.Server.startServer(Server.java:517)
[ERROR]         at runwar.Start.main(Start.java:51)
[ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:129)
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
[ERROR]         at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
[ERROR]         at runwar.Server.createServletDeployment(Server.java:1360)
[ERROR]         at runwar.Server.startServer(Server.java:517)
[ERROR]         at runwar.Start.main(Start.java:51)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.CfmServlet.init(CfmServlet.java:97)
[ERROR]         at coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:121)
[ERROR]         ... 13 more
[INFO ] Runwar: ******************************************************************************
[INFO ] Runwar: *** stopping server 'cherokee-leaseapps' (socket 49490)
[INFO ] Runwar: ******************************************************************************

Server's output stream closed. It's been stopped elsewhere.

Stopping server...



ERROR (5.9.0+00721)

Server process returned failing exit code [1]
```

Comment: What JAVA version are you using?

Comment: I am using the version that comes packaged with Command Box looks like it is version  11.0.19 

IMPLEMENTOR_VERSION="Temurin-11.0.19+7"
JAVA_VERSION="11.0.19"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2023-04-18"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running ColdFusion 11, the latest version of Java that can be used is Java 8, but only with at least hotfix 3.

https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2021/01/table-of-java-to-cf-versions/

To clarify, CommandBox runs on the version of Java that came with it. By default, all CFML servers will use the version that CB uses. But you can run each instance of a CFML engine on a version of Java specific to it.

You'll have to install the latest version of [Java 7](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html) to start. Then apply the hotfixes, then install [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html). You can tell the server instance to use a specific version of Java with the correct config values.

Create a file `server.json` in the root of your CF application. This is where you can set the server values instead of at the command line. Now you should be able to run `server start`.

```
{
    "name": "cf11server",
    "console": true,
    "jvm": {
        "javaHome": "c://path//to//java//8//bin",
    },
    "app": {
        "cfengine": "adobe@11",
    }
}
```

There are a [lot of settings](https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/server.json) you can configure for each server you create in CommandBox.

Comment: So I ended up just using JRE8 without going through the steps of installing 7 and applying the patches. However, this was exactly the direction I needed. Thank you so much.